# Formatting Date/Time in R

Tags: r, date, time, format

Using R, how do I transform the date and time from here, into a "standard" date/time string format?

> 2020-12-30T03:32:30.000Z

Answer (score 1):

Use `?strptime`

```
strptime("2020-12-30T03:32:30.000Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
# [1] "2020-12-30 03:32:30 CET"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
#Code
as.POSIXct(gsub('T|Z',' ','2020-12-30T03:32:30.000Z'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%OS')
```

Output:

```
[1] "2020-12-30 03:32:30 GMT"
```