# R: Converting date/time format 0000-00-00T00:00:00Z to POSIXct

Tags: r, datetime, format, posixct

I have a dataset I exported as `.csv` from a dataframe in R. The dataset contains a date+time column, for which the format was set as `POSIXct` before exporting it as a `.csv` file. When I import the saved `.csv` file back into R, the format of the date+time column has changed into a `character` and looks as follows: `000-00-00T00:00:00Z` (see below the head of part of my data).

```
ID  Timestamp               X_mean      X_min   X_max
1   2021-06-30T08:00:00Z    -0.4313333  -5.914  4.129
2   2021-06-30T08:00:01Z    -0.3817667  -5.641  4.082
3   2021-06-30T08:00:02Z    -0.2770667  -0.484  -0.109
4   2021-06-30T08:00:03Z    -0.3686667  -0.863  -0.148
5   2021-06-30T08:00:04Z    -0.2696667  -0.41   -0.102
6   2021-06-30T08:00:05Z    -0.4150000  -0.734  -0.145
```

I would really like to get the date+time back to a POSIXct variable if possible, so it looks like this again: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, without the '*T*' and the '*Z*'.

I have tried to apply the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667212/converting-datetime-string-to-posixct-date-time-format-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65506672/formatting-date-time-in-r), but they do not seem to work or I am doing something wrong in changing the code to have it work for my dataframe. I only end up with NA's.

Is there a way I can change the format back to `POSIXct`?

Comment: Use `lubridate::ymd_hms(df1$Timestamp)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `ymd_hms` from `lubridate`

```
df1$Timestamp <- lubridate::ymd_hms(df1$Timestamp)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `anytime` function of the [anytime package](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=anytime) was made for this:  reliable and easy parsing of any (reasonable) time format whatever the input data type, with requiring a format.   We can demo it:

##### Code

```
## re-create your data
dat <- read.table(text="ID  Timestamp               X_mean      X_min   X_max
1   2021-06-30T08:00:00Z    -0.4313333  -5.914  4.129
2   2021-06-30T08:00:01Z    -0.3817667  -5.641  4.082
3   2021-06-30T08:00:02Z    -0.2770667  -0.484  -0.109
4   2021-06-30T08:00:03Z    -0.3686667  -0.863  -0.148
5   2021-06-30T08:00:04Z    -0.2696667  -0.41   -0.102
6   2021-06-30T08:00:05Z    -0.4150000  -0.734  -0.145", header=TRUE)

## add a Datetime column
dat$datetime <- anytime::anytime(dat$Timestamp)

## look at dat
dat
```

##### Output

```
> dat <- read.table(text="ID  Timestamp               X_mean      X_min   X_max
+ 1   2021-06-30T08:00:00Z    -0.4313333  -5.914  4.129
+ 2   2021-06-30T08:00:01Z    -0.3817667  -5.641  4.082
+ 3   2021-06-30T08:00:02Z    -0.2770667  -0.484  -0.109
+ 4   2021-06-30T08:00:03Z    -0.3686667  -0.863  -0.148
+ 5   2021-06-30T08:00:04Z    -0.2696667  -0.41   -0.102
+ 6   2021-06-30T08:00:05Z    -0.4150000  -0.734  -0.145", header=TRUE)
> dat$datetime <- anytime::anytime(dat$Timestamp)
> dat
  ID            Timestamp    X_mean  X_min  X_max            datetime
1  1 2021-06-30T08:00:00Z -0.431333 -5.914  4.129 2021-06-30 08:00:00
2  2 2021-06-30T08:00:01Z -0.381767 -5.641  4.082 2021-06-30 08:00:01
3  3 2021-06-30T08:00:02Z -0.277067 -0.484 -0.109 2021-06-30 08:00:02
4  4 2021-06-30T08:00:03Z -0.368667 -0.863 -0.148 2021-06-30 08:00:03
5  5 2021-06-30T08:00:04Z -0.269667 -0.410 -0.102 2021-06-30 08:00:04
6  6 2021-06-30T08:00:05Z -0.415000 -0.734 -0.145 2021-06-30 08:00:05
>
```